# Please help with translation of English to first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

In a certain work on *mereology*, Alfred Tarski claims that the third following statement is deducible from the previous two:

1. The sum of a class is defined as follows: $y$ is the sum of a class $\alpha$ iff all members of $\alpha$ are parts of $y$, and for all $z$, $z$ being a part of $y$ implies that the class of parts of $z$ and the class of parts of all members of $\alpha$ are not disjoint classes. $$\sum  {=} _{Df} \hat {y} \hat {\alpha} (\alpha \subset \overrightarrow {P} {'} y:.(z):zPy.\supset .P {'} {'} \alpha \cap \overrightarrow { P } {'} z\neq \Lambda )$$
2. For all $x$, the only sum of a class containing only $x$, is $x$. $$x=\sum {'} { \iota  {'} x } $$
3. For all $x$, $x$ is a part of $x$. $$(x):xPx$$

(Russell-Peano notation, unfortunately.)

I am trying to automate the proof of this (or example, using Prover9), with no luck so far. Here is my translation:

1. $\forall y,\alpha :sum(y,\alpha )\leftrightarrow ((\forall p:member(p,\alpha )\rightarrow part(p,y))\wedge (\forall z:(part(z,y)\rightarrow \exists q(\exists r:(member(r,\alpha )\wedge part(q,r))\wedge part(q,z)))))$
2. $\forall x,y,\alpha :(member(x,\alpha )\wedge (\neg \exists z:(member(z,\alpha )\wedge (x\neq z)))\wedge sum(y,\alpha ))\rightarrow (x=y)$. Inside the largest parenthesis, the second term ensures that $x$ is the **only** member of $\alpha$.
3. $\forall x:part(x,x)$

Prover9 immediately responds with 'exhausted'. Another theorem prover, SNARK, also fails to find a proof. What mistake am I making?

Comment: It would be clearer if the "definition" of "sum" in (1) were separated out for any statement being asserted in (1).  A proper definition is not an assertion, merely an abbreviation.  It also seems that with two *primitive* relations (`member/2` and `part/2`) there ought to be more axioms that inform their mutual properties.  In principle any *defined* notion (e.g. `sum/2`) is merely a notational convenience, and arguments could be carried out without relying on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a possible origin of the problem is in forgetting that $\alpha$ is a *class* variable.

If we reason "informally", we have that statement 1 is (using a *term* operator for "sum") :

> $y = sum (\alpha)$ **iff** $\forall x(x \in \alpha \rightarrow part(x,y))$ and ...

Statement 2 is simply :

> $\alpha = \{ x \} \rightarrow sum(\alpha) = x$.

Thus, using :

$x = sum ( \{ x \})$

into the definition of "sum", we get :

> > $\forall x(x \in \{ x \} \rightarrow part(x,x))$.

But, by f-o logic : $\forall x (\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\forall x \varphi \rightarrow \forall x \psi)$ and (intuitively) we have : $\forall x(x \in \{ x \})$.

Thus, we may conclude with :

> $\forall x part(x,x)$.

---

*Note*

According to [Principia Mathematica](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/)'s symbolism, we can use $\in$ in the context : $x \in \alpha$.

The "basic" property [see 2nd ed, vol I, page 26] is : $x \in \hat{z}(\phi z) \equiv \phi x$ [in modern notation : $x \in \{ z : \phi(z) \} \equiv \phi(x)$].

$\iota‘x$ is "the class of objects which are identical with $x$" [see vol I, page 37 : $\iota‘x = \hat{y}(y = x)$ **Df**], i.e. the *singleton* : $\{ x \}$.

The "sum" is a binary relation : $\Sigma = \hat{y} \hat{\alpha} \varphi(y,\alpha)$ between a *term* and a *class* [see page 27].

Thus [see page 33] $\Sigma‘\alpha$ is the "descriptive function" associated to the relation $\Sigma$, i.e. it has as value the unique $y$ such that $y\Sigma \alpha$.

Thus, statement 2 means that $x$ is the *sum* of $\iota‘x$, i.e. $x= \Sigma‘ \{ x \}$.

See in Alfred Tarski, [Logic, Semantics, Metamathematics : Papers from 1923 to 1938](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0915144751) (1956), the reprint of *FOUNDATIONS OF THE GEOMETRY OF SOLIDS* (1927), page 24-on.

Page 25, footnote 1 :

> The terms 'individual' and 'class' are used here in the same way as in the well-known work of A.N.Whitehead and B.Russell [*Principia Mathematica*, 2nd ed., i-iii (Cambridge, 1925-7)].

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your informal proof was very helpful. You're right - nothing in my representation indicates that $\alpha$ is a class, apart from the 'member' function. How might this be represented in first-order logic?

Comment: @Atriya - this is not an issue: $member(x,\alpha)$ works well, exactly as the "traditional" $x \in \alpha$. But in set-tehory (e.g.ZFC) we need an axiom to assert the existence of the *pair* : $\{ x,y \}$ where $w \in \{ x,y \}$ iff $w = x \lor w = y$. Thus we have : $\{ x \} = \{ x,x \}$ and obviously $x \in \{ x \}$. Tarski's article must assume some "sort" of class or set theory : *Principia Mathematica*'s one ???

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding the Note to your answer. Your conclusion about Statement 2 is, then, the same as mine - that x is the unique sum of the class containing only x. What is interesting is the 'basic' property of x. It is possible that by including this, the proof may be found by the ATP. As you quote, the basic property is stated by PM as $x \in \hat{z}(\phi z) \equiv \phi x$. Could you please explain this in English or a modern FOL?

Comment: Secondly, on the existence of a pair - thank you for pointing this out. I understand that ZFC is not finitely axiomatizable in FOL, and therefore not appropriate for automated theorem proving. I was looking into NBG (Neumann–Bernays–Gödel) set theory, which is finitely axiomatizable, equivalent to ZFC, and also has an axiom to assert the existence of a pair. If the addition of Russell’s ‘basic’ property of membership does not result in the proof being found, might it be helpful to assert all the axioms of NBG as input to the theorem prover?

Comment: I've edited the answer with the "translation" : $x \in \hat {z}(ϕz) ≡ ϕx$ is : $x \in \{ z : ϕ(z) \} ≡ ϕ(x)$.

Comment: Marked this answer as accepted: although it does not solve the problem, it is a useful and detailed answer.